# Access localhost on Mac from XCode? Phonegap communicating with Ajax to a local Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, ios, localhost, cordova

Is there a way to access `http://localhost:3000/posts` from within an HTML file that's running through Phonegap for the iPhone on the iPhone device (not the simulator), in XCode?

If I have an HTML5 app in Phonegap, I have only been able to access external stylesheets with `file://Users/etc..` or `http://...` when I'm testing it on the iPhone/iPad itself.  If I'm running the simulator, I can access localhost no problem.

Is there a way around this?  I know I can access localhost on the Mac from within Parallels running Windows by doing `http://username.local/posts`, is there something like this for iOS development?

Answer (score 17):

"localhost" always points to `127.0.0.1` in IPv4, which is the current device's loopback network interface. If you open "localhost" from your iPhone, it will point to the iPhone itself.

However, if you are in the same network as your Mac, you can simply use your Mac's IP address, e.g. `http://192.168.0.20:3000/posts`. You can see your current IP address in your Mac's Network Settings.

Also, depending on your network configuration, using the Bonjour name might work as well. For example: `http://mymac.local:3000/posts` if the name of your computer is set to `mymac` in the system preferences' `Sharing` pane.

Comment: Safari keeps stripping off the port number, very annoying

Comment: shift to chrome, no nonsense

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could set up your Mac as a Web Server? See [ehow link](http://www.ehow.com/how_4488955_set-up-web-server-mac.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether you can access localhost on your Mac/PC from your iPhone device, then the answer is no.  There's no way for your iPhone to route to another machine's local host address.

You should get your iPhone on the network that the server resides on and use an accessible IP address to access it.