# Sencha ExtJs Ajax Store not loading in XCode

Tags: ios, ajax, json, xcode, extjs

I have a store with a proxy type as 'ajax'. I'm loading the data from a data.json file. On Windows, everything works in Chrome as well as on Android emulator.

On Mac, this works perfectly if I run it in Safari when I run the sencha server via 'sencha web start'.

However, when I run this in XCode, the json file is not read. After a couple of days of tearing my hair out, it looks like the XCode build is in a temporary folder and the proxy url is not getting resolved to the correct file. At least that is my assumption.

I ran the app in XCode and then tried to debug using Safari Developer (remote debug). In the console if I type Ext.getStore('storename').load(), the load success listener gives the third argument as 'false', which indicates that the store did not load (as per [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load)).

My proxy url is a relative url to the app root so something like this - 'resources/data/datafile.json'.

If I set the url with a slash in the beginning like so '/resources/data/datafile.json', I get an 'invalid resource' error in the Safari Developer console.

I've asked this question at the [Sencha Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?295996-Ajax-Store-not-loading-in-XCode) also.

Additionally, I have added in the 'app.json' file the following -

```
/**
* Extra resources to be copied along when build
*/
"resources": [
    "resources/data"
],
```

This copies the data files over correctly and everything works in all browsers and Android, but not in XCode. From [this particular answer](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?187719-How-to-include-a-data-JSON-file-when-building), it seems like I need to copy the files over to some specific place or set some settings in XCode, but as I'm a newbie in XCode, I don't know how I can go about this.

Any suggestions as to how I can resolve this will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776412/access-localhost-on-mac-from-xcode-phonegap-communicating-with-ajax-to-a-local), in XCode an Ajax call to load a local file will fail, so I guess this cannot work.